# how to add incrementing numbers to a column

Tags: python

Every row that contains 'sample' text in a 'columnname' should be updated **with prefix 'AAAA-'** because I am using that to feed another column. And then **an incrementing number needs to be added** because I am using that to identify the max

from 'sample' to 'AAAA-sample1'

**dataframe = df**

Currently, it looks like below

**columnname**

sample

FFFF-apple

DDDD-orange

sample

BBBB-banana

sample

RRRR-berries

sample

**I want the output to look like below.**

**columnname**

AAAA-sample1

FFFF-apple

DDDD-orange

AAAA-sample2

BBBB-banana

AAAA-sample3

CCCC-berries

AAAA-sample5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a dataframe `df`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnname': [
                   'sample',
                   'FFFF-apple',
                   'DDDD-orange',
                   'sample',
                   'BBBB-banana',
                   'sample',
                   'RRRR-berries',
                   'sample']})

>>> df
     columnname
0        sample
1    FFFF-apple
2   DDDD-orange
3        sample
4   BBBB-banana
5        sample
6  RRRR-berries
7        sample
```

Here is a basic approach using a list comprehension to build the new values and set them with `.loc`:

```py
m = df.columnname == 'sample'
df.loc[m, 'columnname'] = [f'AAAA-sample{i+1}' for i in range(len(df[m]))]

>>> df
     columnname
0  AAAA-sample1
1    FFFF-apple
2   DDDD-orange
3  AAAA-sample2
4   BBBB-banana
5  AAAA-sample3
6  RRRR-berries
7  AAAA-sample4
```

Comment: Thanks a million @fsimonjetz. Worked so perfectly. Very minor change for 'm'. m = df['columnname'] == 'sample' not m = df.columnname == 'sample'

Comment: @Ziggy `df.columnname` and `df['columnname']` are largely synonyms, but the latter is safer for sure. If my answer solved your problem, feel free to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Comment: I am sorry, I am pretty new. Just marked it as 'accepted' and yes your solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lotttt

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each line of text, check if line is "sample" and append AAAA- and the number

```
for i, line in enumerate(text): 
    if line == "sample": 
        print(f"AAAA-{line}{str(i+1)}")
    else:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You haven't specified the column name and data frame in your example above. How can I add those? Do I need to create a new column? or can it update the existing column?

Comment: In your code you don't have any dataframe or anything. Please update your question to include your dataframe code so I can update my answer